# Why is vcomp100.dll not included in my setup project?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-xp, setup-project, setup-deployment

How do I register the file `vcomp100.dll` on my Windows XP box? My compiled Visual C++ program seems to need this file in order to work.

Ironically, when I use Visual Studio Installer's Setup and Deployment Tool, why does the packager does not include this DLL inside my setup.exe? It doesn't seem to be packaged inside the installer executable. Or must I include it manually?

Because when I transfer the installer file to another Windows XP box, my program can install, but does not work because of the `vcomp.dll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you told Visual Studio that your application depends on the OpenMP Library? You shouldn't need to include or copy any DLLs to the machine manually.

See this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293568.aspx) on MSDN for a step-by-step sample.

Comment: I discover that the dll is from Imagemagick's binaries that my program is using. My solution is, I make sure that every machine is installed with Imagemagick binary (by using it own setup.exe) and then, I can install my program :)